# Hagba when rolling Sefer Torah

Tags: hagbah-gelilah

On special occasions, multiple Torah portions are read in a given service ie. Mishpatim and Shekalim. When multiple Sifrei Torah are available, a different Sefer is used for each portion, and each Sefer is formally closed with Hagba and Gelila before the next Sefer is opened and read from.

If only 1 Sefer Torah is available and multiple portions are to be read from different sections which will require rolling, do we do Hagba before rolling the Sefer to the next portion of laining?

Comment: @Mordechai do you do hagbah on fast days between rishon and sheni?

Comment: @DoubleAA, there it is one kriah with a skip; here it is two kriot that should ideally be from separate sefarim.

Comment: @Mordechai you just made that up? What are those categories (one kriah with a skip)?

Comment: Yes, I did. And we don't read on a fast day from two sefarim even when we have them, so the chiluk seems easy.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear, and with my edits I think it is clear enough to be reopened. Welcome!

Comment: BTW, I saw in some modern sefer that there are two practices on this one. The sources cited where too obscure to be found in my beis medrash, and I'd have to serach for the citation again.

Comment: Don't have time to look for the sources, but the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

It's not explicit in Shulchan Aruch but very strongly implies not in Siman 144, sif 3, (and Mishna Brura siman 16) where he says that if you are going to be reading a separate topic (i.e. maftir in a different parsha) you roll the Torah, because reading Maftir from the Torah takes precedence over Kavod HaTzibbur. I would assume you want to mitigate the delay as much as possible, so I would imagine it's only rolling, no hagba. The practice is definitely not to do hagba, at least in many shuls

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Michael and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!